# Hover to click in wordpress menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, navigationbar

I used a theme that I changed to show sub menu horizontally, now I want to show sub menu onClick and not on hover, I'm not good at javascript but I think that this code is about the navigation menu:

```
var nav = {
    init: function() {

        // Add parent class to items with sub-menus
        jQuery("ul.sub-menu").parent().addClass('parent');

        var menuTop = 40;
        var menuTopReset = 80;

        // Enable hover dropdowns for window size above tablet width
        jQuery("nav").find(".menu li.parent").hoverIntent({
            over: function() {
                if (jQuery('#container').width() > 767 || jQuery('body').hasClass('responsive-fixed')) {

                    // Setup menuLeft variable, with main menu value
                    var subMenuWidth = jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().outerWidth(true);
                    var mainMenuItemWidth = jQuery(this).outerWidth(true);
                    var menuLeft = '-' + (Math.round(subMenuWidth / 2) - Math.round(mainMenuItemWidth / 2)) + 'px';
                    var menuContainer = jQuery(this).parent().parent();

                    // Check if this is the top bar menu                            
                    if (menuContainer.hasClass("top-menu")) {
                        if (menuContainer.parent().parent().parent().hasClass("top-bar-menu-right")) {
                        menuLeft = "";
                        } else {
                        menuLeft = "-1px";
                        }
                        menuTop = 30;
                        menuTopReset = 40;
                    } else if (menuContainer.hasClass("header-menu")) {
                        menuLeft = "-1px";
                        menuTop = 28;
                        menuTopReset = 40;
                    } else if (menuContainer.hasClass("mini-menu") || menuContainer.parent().hasClass("mini-menu")) {
                        menuTop = 40;
                        menuTopReset = 58;
                    } else {
                        menuTop = 44;
                        menuTopReset = 64;
                    }

                    // Check if second level dropdown
                    if (jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().parent().parent().hasClass("sub-menu")) {
                        menuLeft = jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().parent().parent().outerWidth(true) - 2;
                    }

                    jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().addClass('show-dropdown').css('top', menuTop);
                }
            },
            out:function() {
                if (jQuery('#container').width() > 767 || jQuery('body').hasClass('responsive-fixed')) {
                    jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().removeClass('show-dropdown').css('top', menuTopReset);
                }
            }
        });

        jQuery(".shopping-bag-item").live("mouseenter", function() {

            var subMenuTop = 44;

            if (jQuery(this).parent().parent().hasClass("mini-menu")) {
                subMenuTop = 40;
            }

            jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().addClass('show-dropdown').css('top', subMenuTop);
        }).live("mouseleave", function() {
            if (jQuery('#container').width() > 767 || jQuery('body').hasClass('responsive-fixed')) {
                jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().removeClass('show-dropdown').css('top', 64);
            }
        });

        // Toggle Mobile Nav show/hide          
        jQuery('a.show-main-nav').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (jQuery('#main-navigation').is(':visible')) {
            jQuery('.header-overlay .header-wrap').css('position', '');
            } else {
            jQuery('.header-overlay .header-wrap').css('position', 'relative');
            }
            jQuery('#main-navigation').toggle();
        });

        jQuery(window).smartresize(function(){  
            if (jQuery('#container').width() > 767 || jQuery('body').hasClass('responsive-fixed')) {
                var menus = jQuery('nav').find('ul.menu');
                menus.each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).css("display", "");
                });
            }
        });

        // Set current language to top bar item
        var currentLanguage = jQuery('li.aux-languages').find('.current-language span').text();
        if (currentLanguage !== "") {
            jQuery('li.aux-languages > a').text(currentLanguage);
        }

    },
    hideNav: function(subnav) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (subnav.css("opacity") === "0") {
                subnav.css("display", "none");
            }
        }, 300);
    }
};
```

I tried to replace "hoverIntent" by "click" but it doesn't work, what can I do?

Comment: Please read [**Minimum**, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post only that code where you have problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening when someone currently hovers, it does one thing while hovering and when they leave it has to d a sort of `cleanup` which are the two functions within `hoverintent`, namely `over` and `out` so the code would need to be split into two event listeners one for `click` of the element and one for `blur`

I have chained the two listeners to the inital selector so it should all work.

```
    var nav = {
        init: function() {

            // Add parent class to items with sub-menus
            jQuery("ul.sub-menu").parent().addClass('parent');

            var menuTop = 40;
            var menuTopReset = 80;

            // Enable click dropdowns for window size above tablet width
jQuery("nav").find(".menu li.parent").on('click', function (event) {
    if($(event.target).parent().hasClass('menu-item-has-children')){
     event.preventDefault();
    };
    if (jQuery('#container').width() > 767 || jQuery('body').hasClass('responsive-fixed')) {
        // Setup menuLeft variable, with main menu value
        var subMenuWidth = jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().outerWidth(true);
        var mainMenuItemWidth = jQuery(this).outerWidth(true);
        var menuLeft = '-' + (Math.round(subMenuWidth / 2) - Math.round(mainMenuItemWidth / 2)) + 'px';
        var menuContainer = jQuery(this).parent().parent();

        // Check if this is the top bar menu                            
        if (menuContainer.hasClass("top-menu")) {
            if (menuContainer.parent().parent().parent().hasClass("top-bar-menu-right")) {
                menuLeft = "";
            } else {
                menuLeft = "-1px";
            }
            menuTop = 30;
            menuTopReset = 40;
        } else if (menuContainer.hasClass("header-menu")) {
            menuLeft = "-1px";
            menuTop = 28;
            menuTopReset = 40;
        } else if (menuContainer.hasClass("mini-menu") || menuContainer.parent().hasClass("mini-menu")) {
            menuTop = 40;
            menuTopReset = 58;
        } else {
            menuTop = 44;
            menuTopReset = 64;
        }

        // Check if second level dropdown
        if (jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().parent().parent().hasClass("sub-menu")) {
            menuLeft = jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().parent().parent().outerWidth(true) - 2;
        }

        jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().addClass('show-dropdown').css('top', menuTop);
    }
}).on('mouseleave',function () {
    if (jQuery('#container').width() > 767 || jQuery('body').hasClass('responsive-fixed')) {
        jQuery(this).find('ul.sub-menu').first().removeClass('show-dropdown').css('top', menuTopReset);
    }
});     
            // Toggle Mobile Nav show/hide          
            jQuery('a.show-main-nav').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (jQuery('#main-navigation').is(':visible')) {
                jQuery('.header-overlay .header-wrap').css('position', '');
                } else {
                jQuery('.header-overlay .header-wrap').css('position', 'relative');
                }
                jQuery('#main-navigation').toggle();
            });

            jQuery(window).smartresize(function(){  
                if (jQuery('#container').width() > 767 || jQuery('body').hasClass('responsive-fixed')) {
                    var menus = jQuery('nav').find('ul.menu');
                    menus.each(function() {
                        jQuery(this).css("display", "");
                    });
                }
            });

            // Set current language to top bar item
            var currentLanguage = jQuery('li.aux-languages').find('.current-language span').text();
            if (currentLanguage !== "") {
                jQuery('li.aux-languages > a').text(currentLanguage);
            }

        },
        hideNav: function(subnav) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (subnav.css("opacity") === "0") {
                    subnav.css("display", "none");
                }
            }, 300);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I guess you didn't think about the link that the parent button had did you?! Hover was probably there for that very good reason! Perhaps you can get rid of the `<a>` tag on the parent and then it might work.

Comment: Also when I do that on your proxy the "blur" function doesn't close the menu (we'll have to use another event).  Perhaps you can setup a jsfiddle.net and we can help more.

Comment: No way to keep the <a> tag without going to the link page ?

Comment: Yeh, good point.  Try updated code. (sorry never posted this comment earlier after update) Fiddle not working as hoped either.

Comment: Thanks, it'better you can see now that the menu show without going to link, but the submenu can't be clicked now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57415/discussion-between-rob-schmuecker-and-solidus).

Answer (score 1):

That seems overly complicated. Do you have a link to the live version?

Usually, when doing a click-to-see submenu with a clickable parent, I set a variable to see whether the menu is open, if not dont go to link. if so, go to link.

An example: http://codepen.io/jhealey5/pen/iLgom

```
    var $handle = $('.sub-menu').prev();

    var opened = 0;
    $handle.on('click', function(e){

      if (opened) {
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        opened = 1;
      }
    });

    $('html').on('click', function(){
      if (opened) {
        $('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        opened = 0;
      }
    });
```

Depending on that menu of yours, you could use something similar. But it's using a lot of code for a menu.